# Is there software to write to RFID cards?

Tags: libraries, writing, com

I have a specialty RFID writing hardware, I just want to write strings onto RFID cards.

Unfortunately they didn't give me any software, but a library. I wasn't intending to program a new GUI and everything just to *write* to the RFID cards. I am actually programming a reader to recognize certain strings from RFID cards.

Does anyone know of RFID writing software?

Comment: Any hardware models?

Comment: Which OS are you wanting to use it on?  Can you contact the RFID hardware company?

Comment: @technie007  I am contacting the company, it seems like an oversight in providing me with the link to the software. I was making sure that I just wasnt missing something obvious like some well known RFID program

Comment: I'm not sure if there are standard protocols for RFID device communications (like say, barcode scanners or GPS devices). :)

Comment: Ones I saw at best buy were a USB port. Their POS system was XP, so it would just be a Windows driver.